# Remove the function and command from the output

Tags: python, defaultdict

I have trying out defaultdict with lamba function. However, I could not get the output I want. I will demonstrate with more details. Below is my code:

```
from collections import defaultdict

the_list = [
    ('Samsung', 'Handphone', 10), 
    ('Samsung', 'Handphone', -1), 
    ('Samsung', 'Tablet', 10),
    ('Sony', 'Handphone', 100)
]

d = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))

for brand, thing, quantity in the_list:
    d[brand][thing] += quantity
```

My result is:

```
defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x02715C70>, {'Sony': defaultdict(<type 
'int'>, {'Handphone': 100}), 'Samsung': defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'Handphone': 
9, 'Tablet': 10})})
```

I want my result to be this:

```
{
    'Samsung': {
        'Handphone': 9, 
        'Tablet': 10
    },
    'Sony': {
        'Handphone': 100
    }
}
```

How am I supposed to do remove the `defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x02715C70>, {'Sony': defaultdict(<type int'>,` to achieve my desired output. Thank you!

Comment: One option is to convert the `defaultdict` to a normal dict, and print it `{k: {k1: d[k][k1] for k1 in d[k]} for k in d}`

Comment: Hi @thefourtheye I don't really get you. Do you mind explain in a full code? Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried [`pprint`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pprint.html)?

Comment: @mangoHero1 what do you by mean `pprint`? I tried using `print` only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just convert each `defaultdict` back to a regular `dict`, you can do it easily using dict comprehension:

```
{ k:dict(v) for k,v in d.items() }
#output
{'Sony': {'Handphone': 100}, 'Samsung': {'Tablet': 10, 'Handphone': 9}}
```

Comment: Hi @Ohad Eytan, do you mind if you show me the full code? I don't really understand it. Sorry, I am still new to python. Thank you.

Comment: @Bakuriu this is the full code. Take your defaultdict and convert it to a regular dict using the first line. Don't include the `>>>` that's a console prompt.

Comment: This is all the code needed (below your code)! I added a link for the documentation where you can read more about _dictionary comprehensions_

Comment: @OhadEytan pardon me. I used your code below my code but I am still not get my desired output. Do you mind if you could show me your ouput using: http://ideone.com/

Comment: Hi @OhadEytan, thank you so much. So sorry that I have to trouble you. I got a better idea on how python works now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try dumping your data in JSON format if you want to remove the type information.

Insert this at the top:

```
import json
```

And this at the bottom:

```
print json.dumps(d, indent=4)
```

And your code should print out like this:

```
{
    "Sony": {
        "Handphone": 100
    }, 
    "Samsung": {
        "Handphone": 9, 
        "Tablet": 10
    }
}
```

This will serve as a solution if order does not matter.

Comment: Hi @mangaHero1, I go the desired output. I am impressed. However, may I ask is there other way other than using "json"?

Comment: [@OhadEytan's solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40068107/6502500) works as well but does not pretty-print the result, which is why I would try playing around with the pprint module I mentioned. This is just a workaround

Comment: Hi @mangoHero1, sorry for misspell your name. Thanks for the insight. This is an awesome feature.

Comment: haha it's no worries. Yes, it is! I'm glad it handled the `defaultdict` data nicely.